# Can I change the binding of RET in gdb?

Tags: gdb

I'd like to disable the gdb behavior where typing a carriage return repeats execution of the last command entered. I'd just like it to do nothing. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that repeating most commmands is a default gdb's behavior and there is no setting to change it. This is how it looks in gdb's source:

```
/* Handle a complete line of input.  This is called by the callback
   mechanism within the readline library.  Deal with incomplete
   commands as well, by saving the partial input in a global
   buffer.  */

static void
command_line_handler (char *rl)
{
 ...
  int repeat = (instream == stdin);
```

So as you can see `repeat` is assigned 1 if `instream` is `STDIN`. There is no other way to assign `repeat` a different value.

So what you can do is to build your own `gdb` executable on your machine from gdb`s source (http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/). But before building change a little the line 591 in gdb/event-top.c. Instead of

```
int repeat = (instream == stdin);
```

write

```
int repeat = 0;
```

Comment: That's a pretty hard core solution, but undeniably workable. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One possible trick that might work -- I didn't try it -- would be to use Python to set the prompt callback to invoke "dont-repeat".

It seems like a reasonable feature request to me that gdb have a setting to disable command repetition.