# Stop gdb repeating last (third-party) command when pressing Enter

Tags: gdb

I'm using some third party macros in gdb, which take a *long* time to run.

I keep pressing Enter, because my muscle memory does that.

This causes the macro to run again.

Is there any way that I can persuade `gdb` *not* to run the previous command on pressing Enter?

I found the `dont-repeat` documentation, but it seems that I have to add it to the user-defined command. These are third-party commands, and I don't particularly want to edit all of them.

Is there any way to turn this behaviour off globally? Or for specific commands (possibly with a wildcard/regex)?

Comment: I guess it is impossible without modifying gdb. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/25024593/72178.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> These are third-party commands, and I don't particularly want to edit
>   all of them.

For a specific command you can define pre hook, turning off repeating last command. This will let you to avoid editing them. For example you can define such pre hook for `continue` command:

```
(gdb) c
The program is not being run.
(gdb) 
The program is not being run.
(gdb) 
The program is not being run.
(gdb) 
The program is not being run.
(gdb) 
The program is not being run.
(gdb) define hook-continue
Type commands for definition of "hook-continue".
End with a line saying just "end".
>dont-repeat
>end
(gdb) c
The program is not being run.
(gdb) 
(gdb) 
(gdb) 
(gdb) 
(gdb)
```

See [hooks doc](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Hooks.html#Hooks).